# sizeToFit not working on a programmatic tableview cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3

I have a basic custom cell with a name label on the left and a price label on the right both set inside another view to customise the spacing. I want the price to change width to whatever the price is and not have it set but when i use sizetofit on the price in the cells init or the cellForRow at function nothing happens. I have looked around but cant see how to get it to work. I cant get the text size when in the init of a cell but it doesnt seem right to be setting the label size within cellForRowAt.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell: SplitterCarouselItemTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "splitterCarouselItemTableViewCell") as! SplitterCarouselItemTableViewCell
    var item = ((allBillSplitters[tableView.tag].items)?.allObjects as! [Item])[indexPath.row]
    if allBillSplitters[tableView.tag].isMainBillSplitter {
        getMainBillSplitterItems(splitter: allBillSplitters[tableView.tag])
        item = mainBillSplitterItems[indexPath.row]
    }
    let count = item.billSplitters?.count

    if count! > 1 {
        cell.name!.text = "\(item.name!)\nsplit \(count!) ways"
        cell.price!.text = "£\(Double(item.price)/Double(count!))"

    } else {
        cell.name!.text = item.name!
        cell.price!.text = "£\(item.price)"
    }

    return cell
}
```

and heres my cell:

```
import UIKit

class SplitterCarouselItemTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    var name: UILabel!
    var price: UILabel!
    var view: UIView!

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:)")
    }

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: "splitterCarouselItemTableViewCell")

        self.setupViews()
    }

    func setupViews() {

        let width = Int(UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 0.88)
        let height = Int(self.bounds.height)

        self.backgroundColor = .clear
        self.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: 45)

        view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 2, width: width, height: height - 4 ))
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.5)

        price = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: width - 80, y: 0, width: 75, height: height))
        price.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15.0)
        price.backgroundColor = .yellow
        price.textAlignment = .right

        name = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 5, y: 0, width: Int(price.frame.width), height: height))
        name.backgroundColor = .red
        name.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15.0)
        name.numberOfLines = 0

        view.addSubview(name)
        view.addSubview(price)

        contentView.addSubview(view)
    }
}
```

Any help would be great, im sure im missing something basic.

Ive added the yellow and red backgrounds for visibility in the screen shot.

[image: Screen Shot]

Comment: can you add image of your outcome? why don't you use constraint and create custom cell in storyboard or Nib?

Comment: @JasmeetKaur The cell and tableview are programmatic because they are nested in a carousel/slide view. I just need the price label to fit the price inside it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to calculate the width of the price label based on text. Below code will help you to find the width

```
extension String {
    func widthWithConstrainedHeight(height: CGFloat, font: UIFont) -> CGFloat {
        let constraintRect = CGSize(width: .greatestFiniteMagnitude, height: height )
        let boundingBox = self.boundingRect(with: constraintRect, options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: font], context: nil)

        return boundingBox.width
    }
}
```

Use above function to find string width and use that width to create frame of price label.

Comment: I just tried to use this within cellForRowAt but nothing changes. I think im using it wrong though this is messy looking but at the moment it is like this `cell.price.frame = CGRect(x: cell.price.frame.width - 80, y: 0, width: (cell.price.text?.widthWithConstrainedHeight(height: cell.view.frame.height, font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15)))!, height: cell.view.frame.height - 4 )`

Comment: can you print the value cell.price.text?.widthWithConstrainedHeight(height: cell.view.frame.height, font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15)))

Answer (score 0):

I'm unclear if you want the frame size to adjust or the font size.  This answer assumes the latter, i.e. that you want a fixed frame width and a font that shrinks as needed to fit....

Try enabling **adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth**,

```
price = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: width - 80, y: 0, width: 75, height: height))
price.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15.0)
price.backgroundColor = .yellow
price.textAlignment = .right
price.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
```

this should shrink the font to fit the width of the label.